# Evaluating XPath Commands with java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Hi I have an xml document like this

```
<root>
  <cert id="1">

  </cert>
  <cert id="2">

  </cert>
  <cert id="3">

  </cert>
</root>
```

now I get a request and want to select the cert with id 2 and want to return it in a function. What is the best way to do this? I thought about XPAth Expression, how can I use them in java? What would be the best output (return value).

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html) on the Java XPath API. It includes info on how to use the API, plus example usage of XPath itself.

Your XPath expression in this scenarion would be

```
/root/cert[@id='2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org) library. The [cookbook](http://dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/cookbook.html) page contains some nice code samples.